# Which version of SonarQube contains the fix for SLVS-1122

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting permissions related errors in my analysis because the process is requesting write access. Before the analysis task starts, if I uncheck the read-only box for the source folder the error does not happen. That is why I'm looking for this fix - 
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-1122

According to the commends on that link, SonarAnalyzer for .Net 1.21 wasn't released until at least Jan 30th. Will this fix be in SonarQube 5.6.6, or will I have to wait until 5.7?

edit: currently running version 5.6.4 through TFS 2015 onprem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing apples and oranges. The fix you want is in the most recently released version of SonarC#. You can upgrade it in your SonarQube server (mostly) independently of your SonarQube server version.